# How to send the All items of combo Box To SQL DB using MySQL query

Tags: c#, mysql

These are the values i want to send to the data base

[image]

```
private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;";
    string Query = "insert into rhms.reservation(no_table)values('" + this.comboBox1.SelectAll() + "');";

    MySqlConnection condatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, condatabase);
    MySqlDataReader myread;
    try
    {
        condatabase.Open();
        myread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("saved");
        this.Refresh();
        while (myread.Read())
        {
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about letting everyone know bit more about 'problem'?

Answer (score 0):

You need set correct info at query string. Now it`s incorrect. Data must separated by commas:

```
string Query = "insert into rhms.reservation(no_table) values " + this.comboBox1.Items
.Select(p=>string.Format("({0})",p.ToString()))
.Aggregate((p1,p2)=>p1 + "," + p2) + ";"
```